# Is it possible to run a trigger on Table Creation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger, table

Simple Question. Is it possible to create a Trigger that runs everytime a Table is created.

The goal is to create a metadata table for each table, but I can worry about dynamically passing the table name later.

The MySQL documentation implies that you can only run triggers on `Inserts`, `Updates`, and `Deletes`.[See: 13.1.15 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).

Comment: MySQL does not have DDL triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

MySQL documentation clearly states applicable events:

[trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)